# Java - inheritance and type of variables when invoking a method

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overriding, invoke

I have some big issue understanding the result of some code.

```
public class ClassA {
    public void stampa(ClassA p) {
        System.out.println("AAA");
    }
}
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    public void stampa(ClassB p) {
        System.out.println("BBB");
    }
    public void stampa(ClassA p) {
        System.out.println("AAA/BBB");
    }
}
public class ClassC extends ClassA {
    public void stampa(ClassC p) {
        System.out.println("CCC");
    }
    public void stampa(ClassA p) {
        System.out.println("AAA/CCC");
    }
}
```

And the main that looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA a1, a2;
    ClassB b1;
    ClassC c1;
    a1 = new ClassB();
    b1 = new ClassB();
    c1 = new ClassC();
    a2 = new ClassC();
    b1.stampa(b1);//BBB
    a1.stampa(b1);//AAA/BBB
    b1.stampa(c1);//AAA/BBB
    c1.stampa(c1);//CCC
    c1.stampa(a1);//AAA/CCC
    a2.stampa(c1);//AAA/CCC
}
```

I'm having a hard time understanding why the result for a1.stampa(b1); is "AAA/BBB" and not "BBB".
As i did understand from inheritance the static type of a1 in compile time is ClassB so i searche for the "stampa" method in ClassB, and for the parameter of the method, the static type is ClassB also, so I will choose the first stampa method of the ClassB.

The same thing also happens when i try to understand the result of a2.stampa(c1); which is "AAA/CCC" and not "CCC".

Can someone please help me to understand what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the following

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    public void stampa(ClassB p) {
```

is not *overriding* this

```
public class ClassA {
    public void stampa(ClassA p) {
```

It is *overloading* it instead...

This means it is an extra method, rather than an override and it can only be accessed via `b1.stampa(b1);`.

Overrides only *happens* if you have the same method signature, with the exception of something called 'co-variant returns', essentially the same concept, but return type is a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem related to overloaded and polymorphism.

```
ClassA a1;
ClassB b1;
...
a1.stampa(b1);
```

The compiler can only determine the two parameters type and the function name be invoked when compile(because of polymorphism).

so "a1.stampa(b1);" make compile find stampa with parameter type ClassB in ClassA, but ClassA don't hava this function, so parameter be demoted, compile find stampa with parameter type ClassA in ClassA. This function is exist, so compiler record in this line that a function with name stampa and parameter type ClassA should be invoke in here.

When program running, a1 is actually a ClassB object, this object overwrite the function with name stampa and parameter type ClassA. Therefore, the final output is "AAA/BBB".

Just remember overload occurs at compile time, and polymorphism occurs at execute time.

Please ignore my broken English.

Answer (score 0):

It is about the difference between *overriding* and *overloading* of methods.

Methods have a [*signature*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), defined by the method name and the parameter types, but not the parameter names or the return type.

You can define multiple methods on a class with the same name, as long as the signatures are different. This is called *overloading*.

If a subclass defines a method with the *same* signature as the superclass, the subclass is *overriding* the superclass method. This means that the subclass method will be called, regardless of the type of the variable used to make the call.

The Java compiler determines *which* method to call at compile-time, i.e. the method signature to use. The actual method with that signature to be called is determined at *run-time*, depending on the actual class of the referenced object.

So, at *compile-time*, for `a1.stampa(b1)` the compiler looks at all the `stampa` on class `ClassA` (because `a1` is of type `ClassA`), and only finds one such method, with signature `stampa(ClassA)`.

At *run-time*, the object referenced by `a1` is actually a `ClassB`, so the `ClassB.stampa(ClassA)` is called, since `ClassB` had overridden the method from `ClassA`.

`ClassB.stampa(ClassA)` then prints `AAA/BBB`.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge the result for a1.stampa(b1); is "AAA/BBB" and not "BBB" because when you are passing b1 to stampa() it will be type casted to superclass reference and because you have overloaded method of superclass and while execution of overloaded methods always subclass methods gets preference so subclass method is executed instead of superclass.

Answer (score 0):

This is **Runtime Polymorphism** which is achieved by the **overridden methods**.
First of all ,you cannot even expect `a1.stampa(b1);` to call a method which is not overriding the parent class method (which in your case happens to be  `public void stampa(ClassB)` ) .This method will never get called from your call as it is not overriding the parent class method.

Now the reason why the `public void stampa(ClassA p)` gets called is because at  runtime the parent class reference variable `a1` refers to the object of `ClassB`.So,the method which overrides the parent class method is called.

The same is the case with your other problem.

For better understanding of Runtime polymorphism you can refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html